# UITableView Set Header Size

Tags: ios, uitableview

How do I change the width of a table view header??

I have a UITableView, and a header which is a UIImageView set in ViewForHeaderInSection.

When I run the app the header stretches to the width of the screen, while the rows (also images) are the width I want.

The height seems to be ok, it's just the width that's the problem.

When I create the Image to set as the header I make a frame for it, but it doesn't do anything.

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

UIImage *tableHeaderImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tableTop"];
UIImageView *headerImageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:tableHeaderImage] autorelease];

headerImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,277,7);
NSLog(@"%@",headerImageView.frame.size.width);    

return headerImageView;
}
```

p.s. it is all programmatically coded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a `UIView`. Once you have set one up add the image view as a subview and return the view:

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(tableView.frame), 7);
    UIImage *tableHeaderImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tableTop"];
    UIImageView *headerImageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:tableHeaderImage] autorelease];

    headerImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,277,7);
    [view addSubview headerImageView];
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) What I ended up doing was tack on an image in the .xib file, not actually connected to the table, which is an absolutely horrible thing to do. I'm going to change it right away.